# Create an "arrow" with html5, css and\or bootstrap above other element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the image below there is a arrow head that sticks out of the middle of the  bottom edge.  How would I be able to create that?  I have it marked with the red rectangle.

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [funkyimg.com](http://funkyimg.com/i/2nBcC.png))</sub>

Green and White appear to be 2 different `<section>` tags. I can't seem to figure out what to google for, and this is the picture of a website and the actual website doesn't have this already, so can't open it and look up the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow border with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189953/arrow-border-with-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pseudo element `after` for that the trick is to `position:absolute;` and borders correctly.

Using `top:100%;` and `border-top` for `:after` adds the down arrow at the bottom of the div.

Using `bottom:100%;` and `border-bottom` for `:after` adds the upward arrow at the top of the div.

```css
.con:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
.con{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="con"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your element `position:relative` it's necessary because for arrow you are going to use `position:absolute`. So relative position will bound its child absolute inside itself. Then make arrow you can use [css-triangle-generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/). instead of making separate element for arrow you can use [before, after pseudo](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) elements.

```css
.section{
  height:250px;
  position:relative;
  background:blue;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
.section:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -30px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px 50px 0 50px;
    border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;  

}
```

```html
<div class="section">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you, it's `CSS`.

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-top-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow

_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
}
```

You have to set the class in your tag, something like this:

```
<div class="arrow_box">
            <h1 > Something </h1>
</div>
```

Check fiddle to see how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/kzvrvbzL/1/